# Ionic 2 fixed content to the right

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 and I have a grid with one row and two columns. I want the second column that is on the right to have a fixed position so I can scroll through the left column with the right column staying fixed.

Is there a way to do this in Ionic 2 or will I have to use CSS for this.

Cheers

Comment: Why don't you use a 'overflow: scroll' on the left column, and set both columns a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use CSS. Ionic does provide a grid system but something like fixed positioning for 1 column still not.

You can use,

```
 position:sticky;
 top:0px;
```

for 1 col. Will have to do more than this. this is just a start up if you are lost with css.

Comment: You might consider adding more code and an example.  Thank you.